# CSS: apply rule only in specific mediaquery?

Tags: css, media-queries

following situation …

```
/* @media screen and (min-width: 480px) */
@media screen and (min-width: 30em) {
     #el { background:red; }
}

/* @media screen and (min-width: 640px) */
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
     #el { background:none; }
}
```

So if the viewport is smaller than 480px `#el` should be red, if the viewport is wider it should have no background-color applied!

Is there some css trick to apply this rule only for `min-width: 30em` so I don't have to "reset" it in the next mediaquery?

Ideas and thoughts on that?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Try in this way

```
@media screen and (min-width: 30em) and (max-width: 40em) {
     #el { background:red; }
}
```

example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2ySNu/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the background for `#e1` to be red below a certain breakpoint, you should use `max-width`. If you want to apply styling rules for viewports that a greater than a certain breakpoint - that's when you should use `min-width`. In your example: `@media screen and (min-width: 30em)`, the background will be red only when the viewport is larger than 30em - once it hits 40em it'll revert back to none (based on your other rule). In order to set  the background for viewports smaller than 480px simply use `max-width`, you don't even have to worry about "resetting" because once the viewport exceeds 480px that rule will not apply.

```
/* @media screen and (max-width: 480px) */
@media screen and (max-width: 30em) {
    #el { background:red; }
}
```

Just remember, the rules you declare in `min-width` will apply to viewports that have a width greater than that breakpoint width you specify. Whereas rules declared in `max-width` will apply to viewports that are less/smaller than the breakpoint width.